# What causes noise when a plane is on the ground?

Tags: jet-engine, noise

What's the loud continuous noise the plane is making when it's on the ground and the (jet) engines are visibly not running (spinning, at least) ?

I was boarding and I thought it was perhaps a compressor for the cabin air but when I entered the cabin it wasn't cool inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be an [Auxiliary Power Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_power_unit), a small jet engine that is used to provide power on the ground when the engines are off and when there is an emergency in the air.

Comment: So, in other words, while the jet engines are visibly not running, an invisible jet engine is running :-P

Comment: I wouldn't call the APU a "jet engine". It's a gas turbine but it is designed to provide power (pneumatic, electric and/or hydraulic) not thrust.